# Shared Preference multiple string set issue

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm trying to copy original String set to other three strings sets. After storing/copying as shown below, if I try to print contents are different. any help appreciated.

```
{       
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("SS", 0);
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(sp.getStringSet("DD", new HashSet<String>()));  

    Object[] array = s.toArray();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putStringSet("CC", s);                   
    editor.commit();

    Set<String> zz = new HashSet<String>(sp.getStringSet("ZZ", new HashSet<String>())); 
    zz.add(array[0].toString());
    zz.add(array[1].toString());

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor_zz = sp.edit();
    editor_zz.putStringSet("ZZ", ZZ);                   
    editor_zz.commit();

    Set<String> hop = new HashSet<String>(sp.getStringSet("HH", new HashSet<String>()));    
    hop.add(array[1].toString());
    hop.add(array[0].toString());

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor_hop = sp.edit();
    editor_hop.putStringSet("HH", hop);                 
    editor_hop.commit();


    logSet = null;
    iterator = null;

    logSet = new HashSet<String>(sp.getStringSet("ZZ", new HashSet<String>()));
    iterator = logSet.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        String zz = iterator.next();
        Log.d("wrong string Y??","ZZList "+zz);
    }


}
```

Comment: How do the copies differ from the original?

Comment: The order of string values are different and the the name of string set, they will be accessed   with respective string set. is there problem in the way it is done.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the order of the strings. Since this is a set, the order is not guaranteed to be preserved,